# How do I make my widgets in tkinter adjust their size automatically with respect to the window size?

Tags: python, tkinter, resize, tkinter-layout

My tkinter window has about 16 buttons all placed equidistant from one another in a square. I used ttk to create these objects and used `place()` to place them on the window. When the user resizes a window by dragging the corner of the window, I want the buttons and the text in the buttons to automatically grow/shrink based on whether the user increases the size or decreases the window size.

Comment: I did use grid to solve this specific problem, but using it gives me another issue(unrelated to this issue)...so I wanted to know whether it is possible to do that with place().

Comment: Grid is the best/easy way, if you want, you can ask about that issue. Place is not the best idea, IMO

Comment: Ahhh...okay, I knew this would happen, I thought there would be a way to achieve this even with place. @Cool Cloud, I have updated the question. How would I resize the buttons based on the window size?

Comment: If you talking about `grid`, then you can configure to use their `weight`, along with `sticky` option to make it grow when someone resizes the window

Comment: ok...do you have any specific link/video i could refer to?

Comment: No, but I can post an answer, as that is what this site is for... :P

Comment: neither `pack` nor `grid` is best for all situations. Sometimes `pack` definitely is best, sometimes `grid` is definitely best. They both have strengths and weaknesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To grow widgets as their size increase I use `weight` option along with `sticky` for `grid` manager. Since you said you are having a square, I have made 16 buttons in 4 rows and 4 columns. So this is what it looks like:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

for i in range(4):
    root.grid_rowconfigure(i,weight=1) # i is the row index
    for j in range(4):
        Button(root,text=f'{4*i+j}th Button', width=10).grid(row=i,column=j,sticky='news')
        root.grid_columnconfigure(j,weight=1) # j is column index

root.mainloop()
```

So `sticky='news'` will make the widget take the entire space on the cell. And `weight` will provide the additional space to propagate for the given row/column.